# From pathlib parts tuple to string path

Tags: python

How to get from tuple constructed by using `parts` in `pathlib` back to actual string path?

```
from pathlib import Path    
p = Path(path)
parts_tuple = p.parts
parts_tuple = parts_arr[:-4]
```

We get smth like `('/', 'Users', 'Yohan', 'Documents')`

How to turn `parts_tuple` to a string path - e.g delimit every part by '/' except first array item (because it is root part - "/"). I care to get a string as an output.

Comment: How about: `'/{}'.format('/'.join(a[1:]))` ?

Comment: sorry, just noticed it's tuple type, not array

Comment: The below solution and the comment above should still work for tuple types :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use the built in OS lib, to keep consistency across OSs.

```
a = ['/', 'Users', 'Yohan', 'Documents']
os.path.join(*a)
```

output:

```
'/Users/Yohan/Documents'
```

Comment: os.path.join(list(parts_tuple))
when I do this I get error TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list

Comment: oops forgot star. hmmm.. not sure what star is doing, but it did the trick

Comment: The star expands the iterator, list, tuple, etc into a flat comma separated params

Comment: BTW, you don't need to convert it into a list, you can just do the operation on a tuple too to increase efficiency a tiny bit :)

Answer (score 12):

If you're using `pathlib` then there's no need to use `os.path`.

Supply the parts to the constructor of `Path` to create a new Path object.

```
>>> Path('/', 'Users', 'Yohan', 'Documents')
WindowsPath('/Users/Yohan/Documents')

>>> Path(*parts_tuple)
WindowsPath('/Users/Yohan/Documents')

>>> path_string = str(Path(*parts_tuple))
'\\Users\\Yohan\\Documents'
```

Answer (score 1):

You should follow LeKhan9 answer.  Suppose a windows OS. We would have:

```
>>> path = "C:/Users/Plankton/Desktop/junk.txt
>>> import os
>>> from pathlib import Path    
>>> p = Path(path)
>>> os.path.join(*p.parts)
'C:\\Users\\Plankton\\Desktop\\junk.txt'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> path = "C:/Users/Plankton/Desktop/junk.txt/1/2/3/4"
>>> from pathlib import Path    
>>> p = Path(path)
>>> p.parents[3]

PosixPath('C:/Users/Plankton/Desktop/junk.txt')
```

Using the `parents` attribute is intersting because it preserves the Path object.